# Visual Studio Installing Windows ASP.NET Core into Docker Linux Container?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, containers, docker-for-windows

I am doing an F5 debug in Visual Studio of a number of microservices running under Linux docker containers. I know the containers are Linux because

- Docker for Windows says *Switch to Windows Containers* on its menu
- `docker container inspect` against my containers shows `"Platform": "linux"`.

Without any obvious changes to `docker-compose` or `dockerfile` files it "feels" like ASP.NET core thinks it is running in a Windows environment. It appears like Visual Studio is causing this.

I get a lot of

- PlatformNotSupportedException
- NotSupportedException
- DirectoryNotFoundException
- DllNotFoundException
- Cannot find or open the PDB file
- realpath(): Invalid argument

and

> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
>   Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
>   to help you develop and test your applications.

This appeared to begin without warning. I've tried all of the following:

- restart docker
- reboot
- uninstall/reinstall docker
- use an older version of the codebase

Nothing seems to work.

Some of the microservices appear to work normally, just slower because exceptions are thrown everywhere. It just may be they aren't making platform specific calls though.

`docker version` shows

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:34:26 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:41:49 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Cannot you analyze at least one of the exceptions to see if it indicates a bug in your code?

Comment: Are you sure that when you hit F5 it runs the app in docker container? There are different debugging profiles can be set in project properties with different launch options such as IIS, IIS Express, Docker, Project or Executable. Make sure you use correct profile.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich, the only profile shown in the toolbar is **Docker Compose**.

Comment: @LexLi, while I haven't analyzed *all* of them, they all originate deep in .NET code outside of my codebase. It's only my machine that is affected as several of my other coworkers don't have this issue. It's environmental seemingly, but haven't been able to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing Visual Studio via the Repair option in Visual Studio Installer fixed the problem.

Unfortunately, I don't know what the root cause was.

Comment: The problem has also not recurred since installing VS 2019.